# How to handle substring with dynamic length in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-parsing

I have a list of domain as follows:

```
facebook.com  
youtube.com/video  
google.com/
github.com/something/somewhere
microsoft.com/default.aspx
```

Now I want to use PowerShell to substring with expected result as follows, in order to create a cleaned format)

```
facebook.com
youtube.com
google.com
github.com
microsoft.com
```

With the PowerShell as follows,

```
ForEach($website in $list){
    $finalList  = $website.Substring(0,$website.IndexOf('/'))
    Write-Output $finalList 
}
```

The problem with this PowerShell is when the loop run at **facebook.co**m it thrown an error **Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.** because **facebook.com** has no forward slash (/) so the index always returns -1

I'm thinking of a way to exclude facebook.com but still can't seem to figure out a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using the methods of .NET types *directly* in PowerShell - such as `.Substring()` of the `[string]` type - is always an option, PowerShell's native features usually offer a more concise and elegant solution:

```
# Create the list (an array of strings).
$list = @'
facebook.com  
youtube.com/video  
google.com/
github.com/something/somewhere
microsoft.com/default.aspx
'@ -split '\r?\n'

foreach ($website in $list) {
  # Split the list element by '/' (if present) and output the 1st token.
  ($website -split '/')[0]
}
```

The above yields:

```
facebook.com  
youtube.com
google.com
github.com
microsoft.com
```

The [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) returns the array of tokens contained in the LHS (`$website`) based on the RHS separator (`/`), and index `[0]` returns the 1st such token.

If the LHS happens to contain no instance of the separator, a single-element array is returned, which can still be safely accessed with index `[0]`.

If the list of URLs also contains *port numbers* (e.g., `website.com:8888`) modify the split command as follows:

```
($website -split '[/:]')[0]
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `-split` operator supports *regular expressions* as the separator definition, and character set `[/:]` matches both a (single) `/` and a `:`